# How to add up all order amounts for a month and year. SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

So Am having a problem adding up all the results up by the year and month

So I am joining four tables to come up with my results

I have a `Customer` table:

```
Cust_id , f_name ,  L_name
```

`Products` table:

```
Product_id, retail_price , cost_price
```

`Orders` table:

```
Order id, order_date,Cust_id,
```

`Order_details` table :

```
Order_id Product_id, Quantity,
```

So this is how my query is for now

```
SELECT 
    C.FNAME,C.LNAME,
    SUM (P.RETAILPRICE * OD.QUANTITY) AS "Total $ spent by Customer",
    DATENAME(yyyy,o.ORDER_DATE) AS YEAR, 
    DATENAME(MM,o.ORDER_DATE) AS MONTH
FROM
    ORDER_DETAILS OD
JOIN 
    PRODUCTS P ON OD.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID
JOIN 
    ORDERS O ON O.ORDER_ID = OD.ORDER_ID
JOIN 
    CUSTOMER C ON C.CUST_ID = O.CUST_ID
GROUP BY  
    O.ORDER_DATE, C.FNAME,C.LNAME
ORDER BY 
    DATENAME(yyyy, o.ORDER_DATE), DATENAME(MM, o.ORDER_DATE)
```

This query returns results like this:

```
customer     sum        spend yr month
--------------------------------------
Bob Johnson    400.00   2010     jan
Kevin Cruz     123.10   2010     jan
Emily Sheily    74.12   2010     jan 
Lily Phantom   475.95   2010     jan 
Kevin Cruz     148.52   2010     jan
```

I would like that the orders made from Kevin Cruz to be added into one sum for the year of jan 2010.

I have that happen all over my results. Cruz made two orders in that month for that year but I can't seem to add them up.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `order_date` in the `group by`.  You wan the year and month:

```
SELECT C.FNAME,C.LNAME,
       SUM(P.RETAILPRICE * OD.QUANTITY) AS "Total $ spent by Customer",
       DATENAME(year, o.ORDER_DATE) AS YEAR, 
       DATENAME(month, o.ORDER_DATE) AS MONTH
FROM ORDER_DETAILS OD JOIN PRODUCTS
     P
     ON OD.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID JOIN
     ORDERS O
     ON O.ORDER_ID = OD.ORDER_ID JOIN
     CUSTOMER C
     ON C.CUST_ID = O.CUST_ID
GROUP BY DATENAME(year, o.ORDER_DATE), DATENAME(month, o.ORDER_DATE), C.FNAME,C.LNAME
ORDER BY DATENAME(year, o.ORDER_DATE), 
         DATENAME(month, o.ORDER_DATE);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know the answer was so simple. I been trying distinct commands to try getting that results. It works how I want it 
Thank you